# Run Azure WebJob from Azure WebSite in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a web site in azure running in php and a webjob also running in php.

To run my webjob, i have to login into azure portal and click on "run webjob". (By the time, i want it to be on demand and not scheduled)

Does anyone know how to run my webjob from my website??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical pattern is for the website to send a message in a queue that will be picked up by the WebJob.

If your new to Azure Queues, check this "How to use the Queue service from PHP" from the Azure documentation: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-queues/